# Libgdx: import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: types, import, compiler-errors, libgdx

Yeah i'm new to Libgdx and still semi-new to java, im going off of Steigerts tutorials, which i realize is a bit dated, but anyways im trying to make the desktoplauncher and this import won't work.

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;

it says it cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Hi, long since this question was asked, but you really should accept one of the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use gdx setup ui http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/gdx-setup-ui.jar

Run it(java -jar). It will automatically generate all the libgdx projects for you. Then just import them in your workspace.

Also, libgdx is growing very fast. If you notice a tutorial is outdated, do not keep following it and better look for another one. And you can also look in these examples, they are often updated: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/demos

Comment: If one really wants to fix up a project's build paths (which is probably the root issue here) without using gdx-setup-ui, look at the wiki on manual setup: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup  But just glancing over that wiki is probably a good motivator to use gdx-setup-ui.

Answer (score 4):

Importing the libGDX to the Eclipse was a big problem when I started too. I wanted to check the Examples and Tests before begin anything so here is what I did:

I downloaded the Master Zip from the github in this link https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx and imported EVERYTHING into Eclipse. This is a very important thing to pay attention. Some projects depends on the gdx project. After importing you need to correct the Build Path. For this you should click each project with problems and search for the missing jar. The jars are downloaded rom the libGDX last release http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/downloads/list.

If you just want to import the Jars to your project you can simply click on the Build Path>Libraries>Add External Jar and Search the missing jar where you downloaded the libGDX build.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the error although I used the `gdx-setup-ui.jar` and later I noticed that I had errors during the setup that I didn't notice, so check it does say `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`